# Call a Java Agent without -javaagent:MyJavaAgent?

Tags: java

Is it possible to run an application with a `javaagent` without calling 
`java -javaagent:MyJavaAgent -jar MyAppToRun` with a batch file ? (To call the `javaagent` directly when the app is launching, without passing by an batch file)

If yes, how? By modifying the manifest file of `MyAppToRun`? By modifying is code?

Thanks!

Comment: Short question: why is the mentioned approach not sufficient ?

Comment: Because this is an java game hosted on a web server, I don't have the right to modifying the launch argument, but I've the right to add it what I wan't, with javaagent, but I don't know how to do. So do you have an idea ?

Comment: @vrackfall it is possible to start agents after startup of the JVM, see the answers to the linked question

Comment: Doesnt the link also provide info about modifying the manifest ? That should do the job @wero

Comment: Ok I will see if it's work

Comment: I tried to modify the main class of my class like that (what is highlighted is that I added) : http://pastebin.com/tWTPkEJw

Comment: Should it work ?                                                                                                         Also could I modify this line to add a side like in the command (                              -javaagent:MyJavaAgent=-MCSide:Client) :                      vm.loadAgent(jarFilePath, "PMLCore/PMLPremain.jar");